# How to write dependency rules in rpm .spec file for RHEL OS

Tags: linux, rpm, dependencies

I need to build one rpm package, that should be dependent on the installation of another rpm package.

On my PC, the dependent package has been installed, with a name like `abcd-1425-a.x86_64`.

I wrote my .spec file like following:

```
Requires: abcd = 1425-a.x86_64
```

However, it shows an error during installation.

```
error: Failed dependencies:
     abcd = 1425-a.x86_64 is needed by patch_xxxxxx
```

According to rpm dependency rule, I thought `1425` should be the rpm version, where `a.x86_64` should be the release. I also tried to delete `x86_64`, which didn't work.

How to define this rule?

Answer (score 1):

Your version numbering is odd, it could be it confuses rpm.

usually requirements are declared like this: `perl >= 1:5.6.0`.

I advise fixing the numbering, or using serial tags.

With serial tags, you can effectively ignore the version number.

More on this argument here : http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-depend-manual-dependencies.html

PS: max-rpm is all you should ever need as a reference to build rpm packages

Comment: how to get serial number?

Comment: I posted a link. Did you even follow it?